# To show that Bloch's constant satisfies $B\leq \pi/4$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that Bloch's constant satisfies $B\leq \pi/4$ by using the function 
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}\log \frac{1+z}{1-z}$$
where Bloch's constant is defined as follows

> There is a universal constant $B$ such that that for $f\in \mathcal{O}(\mathbb{D})$ which is normalized so that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$, $f(\mathbb{D})$ contains a disk of radius at least $L$ that is the injective image of a subset of $\mathbb{D}$. The smallest such $B$ is called Bloch’s constant.

---

My attempt:

It is natural to reduce this problem to the following:

there is a disk of radius $\frac{\pi}{4}$ in $f(\mathbb{D})$

Now it seems that I don't have any tool to find such a  circle...

Comment: Think about Schwartz lemma and open mapping theorem

Comment: Showing that there is a disk of radius $\pi/4$ in the image does not show that $B \le \pi/4$. I mean, there is also a disk of radius $0.000001$ in the image and that does not imply that $B \le 0.000001$. I think one would have to show an example of an $f$ whose image does not contain any disk with radius *bigger than* $\pi/4$. --- ($B$ is the infimum of the radii of *maximal* disks in images of functions satisfying the conditions in Bloch's theorem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $\log$ stands for the principal branch of the logarithm. Also, I will denote the principal value of the argument by $\arg $.

The map $z\mapsto \frac{1+z}{1-z}=w$ maps $\mathbb D$ onto the right half-plane. The latter consists of the circular arcs $|w|=r, -\pi < \arg w < \pi$.

Recall that the function $\xi=\log w$ maps the circular arc $|w|=r$, $\theta_1\le \arg(w)\le \theta_2$ onto the vertical line segment $u=\ln r, \theta_1\le v \le \theta_2$, where $u$ and $v$ stand for the real and imaginary parts of $\xi$, respectively, and $\ln$ stands for the real logarithm. Thus the right half-plane is mapped under the (principal branch of the complex) logarithm onto the (symmetric) strip in the right half-plane of "vertical diameter" $2\pi$, i.e., onto the set $u>0, -\pi < v < \pi$.

Finally, the map $\xi\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\xi$ maps the latter strip onto the strip of diameter $\pi$ in the right half-plane. Such a strip contains a disc of radius $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: But if I understand correctly, the maximal radius of disks contained in the image here is actually $\pi/2$, and hence we can only infer that $B \le \pi/2$ from this. Cf. my comment under the question. Or do I overlook something?